# How to make real asynchronous client via boost asio

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I need to write a dynamic library which should export three functions:

```
bool init_sender(const char* ip_addr, int port);
void cleanup_sender();
void send_command(const char* cmd, int len);
```

`init_sender` should connect to server synchronously and return `true` / `false` according to whether it was success or not.

`cleanup_sender` should wait for all commands to be completed and then returns.

`send_command` should send the specified command to the server asynchronously and return as fast as possible.

So I wrote the following code:

```
boost::asio::io_service                         g_io_service;
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>  g_work;
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket                    g_sock(g_io_service);
boost::thread                                   g_io_service_th;

void io_service_processor()
{
  g_io_service.run();
}

bool __stdcall init_sender(const char* ip_addr, int port)
{
  try
  {
    g_work = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_service::work>(g_io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(g_io_service);
    boost::asio::connect(g_sock, resolver.resolve({ ip_addr, std::to_string(port) }));
    g_io_service_th = boost::thread(io_service_processor);
    return true;
  }
  catch (const std::exception& ex)
  {
    return false;
  }
}

void __stdcall cleanup_sender()
{
  g_work.reset();
  if (g_io_service_th.joinable())
  {
    g_io_service_th.join();
  }
}

void async_write_cb(
  const boost::system::error_code& error,
  std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  // TODO: implement
}

void __stdcall send_command(const char* cmd, int len)
{
  boost::asio::async_write(g_sock, boost::asio::buffer(cmd, len), async_write_cb);
}
```

As far as I knew from boost asio documentation, all my command posted by `async_write` function call will be executed from one single thread (the one that contains `run` function call -- `g_io_service_th` in my case). Am I right? If so, it doesn't seem to be fully asynchronous to me. What could I do to change this behavior and send several commands at the same time from several threads? Should I create `boost::thread_group` like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < pool_size; ++i)
{
  _thread_group.create_thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &_io_service));                             
}
```

or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking a bit question and there's a lot to learn. Probably the most important thing to understand is how to use a work object.

edit: reference to async_write restriction:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html

quoting from the documentation:

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed operation. **The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes.**

Your asio thread code should look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>


struct service_loop
{
    using io_service = boost::asio::io_service;

    io_service& get_io_service() {
        return _io_service;
    }

    service_loop(size_t threads = 1)
    : _strand(_io_service)
    , _work(_io_service)
    , _socket(_io_service)
    {
        for(size_t i = 0 ; i < threads ; ++i)
            add_thread();
    }

    ~service_loop() {
        stop();
    }

    // adding buffered sequential writes...

    void write(const char* data, size_t length)
    {
        _strand.dispatch([this, v = std::vector<char>(data, data + length)] {
            _write_buffer.insert(std::end(_write_buffer), v.begin(), v.end());
            check_write();
        });

    }
private:
    std::vector<char> _write_buffer;
    bool _writing;

    void check_write()
    {
        if (!_writing and !_write_buffer.empty()) {
            auto pv = std::make_shared<std::vector<char>>(std::move(_write_buffer));
            _writing = true;
            _write_buffer.clear();
            boost::asio::async_write(_socket,
                                     boost::asio::buffer(*pv),
                                     [this, pv] (const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t written) {
                                         _strand.dispatch(std::bind(&service_loop::handle_write,
                                                                    this,
                                                                    ec,
                                                                    written));
                                     });
        }
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t written)
    {
        _writing = false;
        if (ec) {
            // handle error somehow
        }
        else {
            check_write();
        }
    }

private:
    io_service _io_service;
    io_service::strand _strand;
    io_service::work _work;
    std::vector<std::thread> _threads;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;

    void add_thread()
    {
        _threads.emplace_back(std::bind(&service_loop::run_thread, this));
    }

    void stop()
    {
        _io_service.stop();
        for(auto& t : _threads) {
            if(t.joinable()) t.join();
        }
    }

    void run_thread()
    {
        while(!_io_service.stopped())
        {
            try {
                _io_service.run();
            }
            catch(const std::exception& e) {
                // report exceptions here
            }
        }
    }
};


using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    service_loop sl;
    sl.write("hello", 5);
    sl.write(" world", 6);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But was I right? What's wrong with my code so you said "Probably the most important thing to understand is how to use a work object"?

Comment: at the moment, your io_service loop will stop if any callback function throws an exception. This is probably not what you want. however, as a bare bones implementation you're on the right track. HOWEVER. bare in mind that each socket must have AT MOST ONE async write in progress at any one time. You will want to maintain a "write queue" which you will want to drain in your completion handler (remember to guard it with mutexes).

Comment: "at the moment, your io_service loop will stop if any callback function throws an exception" -- do you mean `async_write_cb` in my case? "bare in mind that each socket must have AT MOST ONE async write in progress at any one time" -- are you sure? Where did you read about it?

Comment: @FrozenHeart updated example to include thread safety and protection of the async composed operation. also included a link and quote to documentation.

Comment: I could ask you back "what is a **real** asynchronous ..." and "what is a '**not real**' asynchronous ...".    
Is a "**not real boolean**" can be equal to 0.5 ?

Comment: @Jean Davy Ah, thanks. What's the reason of `async_write` then? I have to create and maintain thread pool by myself and ensure that there's no other `async_write` calls at the same time? It seems that it'll be much easier to just have synchronous operations within my own thread pool based on boost::asio::io_service. Or is it the same thing about parallel synchronous write calls for the same socket?

Comment: @FrozenHeart think about that for a moment. Would two simultaneous writes to a socket on 2 threads make sense? Of course not. The one-write-operation-at-a-time (same applied to read) is a limitation of *all* I/O when performed asynchronously. This is simply the nature of I/O.

Comment: Ok, then, what's the point of using `async_write` instead of its synchronous analogue inside one single thread that just get them from some kind of queue and sending them one by one?

Comment: ...because async_write allows you to write to *many* sockets *at once*, one write at a time **per socket**... *and* your thread can get on with something else while you're waiting for the send to complete.